# Should I set multiple element bindings on $(document) in single or separate calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm trying to clean up and improve some code. There is a fairly large snippet which attaches multiple events to `$(document)` like so:

```
$(document).on('eventA.nameA', '#pageA', function(){
    // do sth
});

$(document).on('eventB.nameB', '#pageB', function(){
    // do sth
});

$(document).on('eventC.nameC', '#pageC', function(){
    // do sth
});
```

So basically all of the event bindings go directly on the document.

**Question:**

Is there a limit (I found about 50 separate doc bindings ) and what's the advantage/disadvantage of setting this on a single selector like so:

```
$(document)
    .on('eventA.nameA', '#pageA', function(){
        // do sth
    })
    .on('eventB.nameB', '#pageB', function(){
        // do sth
    })
    .on('eventC.nameC', '#pageC', function(){
        // do sth
    });
```

Most of the bindings are page-specific (it's a Jquery Mobile application, so once a page is pulled into the DOM, its bindings are set like this). So there is really no other place to put these bindings, because will be pulled in and out while `$(document)` persists.

Thanks for input!

Comment: You can also use `.on('eventA.nameA eventB.nameB eventC.nameC', '#pageA, #pageB, #pageC', function(){/*...*/});`, but then you do have to use checks to assess what event was fired and which element it was fired on...

Comment: good point, but I'm at 50 document bindings, so this will be a long line of code :-)

Comment: Absolutely. But if you've got fifty bindings I think I'd be looking at using some form of array, or map, to pass the requisite events and targets into the method.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Since it's delegation, isn't that just doing what jQuery does in the background, in the foreground?

Comment: and each binding has its individual method(s) inside the , function()

Comment: @minitech, yes. My point was that I'd try to document each of the events, and targets, in a specific array/map just to avoid having to individually write each of those into the method. (This doesn't *simplify* anything, it just avoids the 'long-line,' uh, 'problem.')

Comment: pardon my visual description ;-)

Comment: @DavidThomas: do you have a small snippet how this would look like?

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of having them on a single selector is that you avoid calling `$(document)` each time (which has a smaller overhead, because `$(document)` gets cached). The disadvantage is that they all have to be right after one another, and you indent them one more level. It's not really important.

What *is* important is that if those are close to the real selectors, using delegation on `document` for ID selectors is probably really wasteful. Just wait until the document's ready, or update the event handlers when the elements are updated - especially if all these elements won't actually exist on the same page at the same time. If the selectors are actually more complex than that, disregard this paragraph :-)

Comment: ok. Thanks for the info. I'd say most are close to real selectors = pages (like #login, #register, #imprint) and I'm mostly listening to the JQM `pagebeforeshow` and `pageshow` events. The pages are not there when the application inits, so everythings tacked to the document. For pages, the other alternative would be to listen to the page itself, but that would just be "1 level down", so I'm probably taking the cached `$(document)`.

Comment: @frequent: Can whatever makes the pages add its own event handlers, then?

Comment: Uhm... if you mean JQM having it's own custom events, then yes - see [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: @frequent: Where do the pages come from?

Comment: pages are .html files. If you start on index.html, Jquery Mobile will make this the "anchor" page, which will always stay in the DOM. If you go to page2.html, Jquery Mobile will pull in the html file page2.html via AJAX and only use what's between the `<div data-role="page" id="#pageB">`. So you have two pages in the DOM (index, pageB). When you go to pageC, pageC is loaded via AJAX, pageB is removed, pageC is shown. So always two pages in the DOM and $('document') will be "alive" for the length the application is running.

Comment: which means the full application logic needs to be in a single js file, hence the 50 bindings. This file must be on every page, but it will only be loaded on the first page the user requests and disregarded on all other pages.

Comment: @frequent: And is there some kind of "page loaded event" that you can use? It seems to me like `pageshow` fits the bill, but apparently not...

Comment: I'm using pageshow and mostly pagebeforeshow. So you are correct. So my snippet above should read `$(doc).on("pageshow", "index", func(){}).on("pageshow","pageB",func(){}).on("pageshow","pageC",func(){})` and so on.